# What are the vulnerabilities of sending a not encrypted password to server?

Tags: php, bcrypt

I am trying to encrypt my password with bcrypt in android studios, but to no avail. I have researched this  http://www.mindrot.org/files/jBCrypt/jBCrypt-0.2-doc/ but cannot get this library to work and it doesn't seem to have been resolved for the user who asked the question.

So would it be safe to send the password not encrypted using the android volley library and encrypt the password in php once it has been received on the server? What are the vulnerabilities of encrypting the password out of the application?

Comment: First and foremost: what security *risk* are you trying to mitigate by encrypting the password? Are you using a TLS encrypted connection for communicating with the server? I hope you're not storing the password "encrypted", but *hashed* on the server?

Comment: Yes hashed on the server and I understand now how to protect it is to use a TLS encrypted connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send your passwords not encrypted over a non-encrypted channel (e.g. plain http without ssl) everyone can read that password.

Imagine the user of your app is signed in in a public WIFI-hotspot. If anyone in this wifi captures the wifi-data send through the network, he will get the package containing the password and username of this user (given this user has to log in while he uses this wifi).

So you could use two solutions:

- Manually implement an encryption in your software on server and clientside
- Use a existing solution as SSL with HTTP (HTTPS)

Comment: Ok thank you I understand much better now. So would you recommend both solutions or would SSL(TLS) suffice?

Comment: SSL(TSL) is in most cases enough